# Add close script for .mp4

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

A script to close a **video.mp4** when it finish to go back on the **original page** please?

This is the example script:

```
 <li><a href="#"><a href="video/aps_production.mp4"><p>Sharing experience video</p></a></li>
```

It is for CSS3, HTML5 and JS. (jQuery1.8.2). It is for iPhone.

I've searched the net by couldn't see an obvious one?

Comment: what do you mean by a "close" script?

Comment: he means that he wants to go back to the homepage when the video finishes playing.

Comment: Yes thats it..to go back on the original page please?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. What you are using the browser directly to read the video, therefore you have no control over it. Use the video tag and the fullscreen attribute instead.

Comment: Why not just embed the video tag in the page directly? The user clicks play, the video plays in full screen by default on the iPhone, then it returns to the page. <video src="video/aps_production.mp4" controls/>

Comment: This is for iPhone not for browser window.

Comment: @TimHayes 5. Yes, I've that running ok. I've a container with iframe that play video and close it back to orignial page ok. I'm talking about a browse catergory with a list in name as words e.g. <li><a href="#"><a href="video/aps_production.mp4"><p>Sharing experience video</p></a></li>. I could embed video tag in the page directly but is there an option as a link instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html) there are some informations.
You could use [video.js](http://videojs.com/docs/api/) to make your life easier there is an `ended` event on which you could bind.

iOS sadly [does not](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) support the fullscreen API.

If you really want to use `a` here is how you could do it.

**html:**

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<video id="video" style="display:none"></video>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("a[href$='.mp4']").click(function(ev){
  // use http://videojs.com/docs/api/ do get doc on how to use video.js

  var player = _v_("video");

  player.src($(this).attr('href'));
  player.requestFullScreen();
  $("#video").show();
  player.addEvent("ended", function(){
    // do what you want to do at the end of the video
    player..cancelFullScreen();
    $("#video").hide();
  });

  return false;
})
```

[doc for attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

DISCLAIMER: I've never use video.js, I'm expecting it to work in this case, I just selected what seems to be the best tool for you. I've gave you hotlinks, hosted on CDN, if you are doing a PhoneGap app, replace them by a self hosted version.

Comment: Can you do something like this: <a href="video/aps_production.mp4" "controls">

Comment: No, when you use a `a` tag it just leave your page, you have no controle. The browser is playing the video at the main file, you have no html no js, you can't do a thing.

Comment: Ok. I've long list of video using iframe with description - that is fine of its own. I've a browse category with a list of video in words only as <li><a href="#"><a href="video/aps_production.mp4"><p>Sharing experience video</p></a> on top pf a page. That mean I cannot close it if a user decide to click a word link and cannot close it back to the same page? If I try video.js will there be a close event?

Comment: As long as you are not embedding the video you can not do anything, you have no control. You must use the `<video>` tag

Comment: I see. I think an anchor link from browse category with a list of video in words only is probably a best solution. That mean if users click a video link in text/words link and it will immediately anchor directly to one of the video container with video description including iframe video.

Comment: I've read the video.js and I see currentTime == duration where do I add this in your improved response?

Comment: Do I have to fill in where the comments are?  // set the video
  // use http://videojs.com/docs/api/ do get doc on how to use video.js
  return false;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18315/discussion-between-3on-and-irishgirl)